# Can I reorder an application search result?

Tags: unity, lenses

I want to open "LibreOffice Calc" and type in "Cal" in the search bar. I can see Calculator and LibreOffice Calc. Now I could use cursor keys or mouse to select LibreOffice Calc. But this is not what I want! What I want is to reorder the result! I want to have LibreOffice Calc BEFORE Calc, because this would be my preferred result (I just have to press enter if LibreOffice would be the first match).

Is that possible? Can I teach Unity to show result a certain way? Launchy (for Windows) e.g., a keystroke launcher, can do that! (Gnome-Do also works!)

Do you have some tips for me?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I know at least in Gnome-Shell that Calc comes first. What about typing searching for libreoffice instead? Since calc comes first in alphabetical order, theoretically it should show up first. I'll try it out when I login to a Unity session and see if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: I know how to get around. But that is not my itention, because it's a general problem. Another example would be Tomahawk and Tomboy. I want to execute Tomboy if I search for "Tom". I'm a lazy man and I want to save some keystrokes. ;) By the way: If I type "Cal" LibreOffice Calc is before Calculator in the list. If I type "Calc" it's the other way. Calculator is before LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that unity will use what you most used.

It remember what it's the application that you normally click when typed some words and then bring it to first place (and the same with second, etc).

In my desktop, when I type "calc" it's libre office calc what appear first.

I have searched a little more and found that unity app lens have a bug related:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-applications/+bug/737394

Most frequently used app is only updated when an app it's installed or removed.

Comment: I never use LibreOffice calc, and always use the calculator, unfortunately the calculator never shows up first

Comment: The linked bug appears to have been resolved, but I still get Libreoffice before Calculator when I type "calc". I noticed "cal" matches Calculator first. There's probably an exact-word-match that takes priority, so typing "cal" might be a workaround for folks.