# Suppressing suggest application in lens

Tags: lenses

When I use the lens to run the calculator (which if often), I can't type just 'calc[enter]' (which is what my muscle memory does), I have to type 'calcu[enter]' otherwise LibreOffice Calc starts.

How can I suppress LibreOffice Calc from showing in the list. Or better still, how can I ensure the calculator program has precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out here: [Can I reorder an application search result?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81155/can-i-reorder-an-application-search-result?rq=1)

The user had a similar problem (possible dupe?) and the top answer should solve your problem, or at least help you along the way to solving it!